# Issue with View not overlapping other View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-relativelayout, android-viewgroup

My Requirement is that i need to show information on some event which needs to be shown at bottom. I created a layout and when that event is happened i am using below method:

**XML Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/maincontainer"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            tools:context=".HomeActivity"
>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="BB"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="AA"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="PP"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="GG"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code to show bottom view:**

```
// To check main container where new view is to be added
       android.view.ViewGroup insertPoint = (android.view.ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.maincontainer);

// New View that needs to be added
        android.view.LayoutInflater vi = (android.view.LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(android.content.Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        android.view.View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.app_flow_error, null);

        android.widget.TextView textView = (android.widget.TextView) v.findViewById(cR.id.information_message);
        textView.setText("Showing error");

//Defining the params value for new view that needs to be added

        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(android.widget.RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        insertPoint.addView(v, insertPoint.getChildCount()-1, layoutParams);

        v.setHovered(true);
```

The view that needs to be shown at bottom, take bottom screen fully, but the Button "BB" shows up .

Can you let me know what wrong actually i am doing, so that button "BB" should hide when new view is added at bottom?

See this [image: "BB" should hide with new view that i am adding]

Comment: add your layout file. And putting red text on red bg is bit counter-clever

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski : Layout file added

Comment: get that button and hide it, you can use button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Add **complete** layout file

Comment: @KaranMer : i want to make generic method to show error so i cannot use button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski : complete layout added

Comment: add v.bringToFront() to your code and you'll be good to go I guess.

Comment: why cant you use setvisibility? will you please explain? and what is this generic method btw

Comment: and also add v.setClickable(true) to prevent clicks on "BB" when your snackbar is shown.

Comment: @ErfanMowlaei : I tried v.bringToFront()  but i haven`t got any success. If "BB" button is not visible and it got hide by snackbar then it will not be able to take events. My issue is why "BB" is not hidden when i am adding new View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For test purposes, try using a `(Relative, Linear etc.)Layout` instead of the BB `Button` and see if it works in this case (by that I mean see if the red layout is on top of the other layout). I suspect it is because the `Button` has a elevation specified (by default, not by you) and it is "raised" on top of what you are showing (I guess you are running on Lollipop+). If that is the case, you could set a elevation to your red layout that is bigger than the `Button`'s or use a layout that already has that (`CardView`?)

Comment: Yes you are correct i am running application on Lolipop and you have identified correctly that because of Button Z ` axis value Button is popping out from newly added view.

Comment: remove the elevation dude, it is not supported in previous versions and may cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aah, took some time (10 mins) but I figured it out. you made two mistakes, first in inflating and second one followed by that in getting layoutParams, so here's what will work for you:

```
//test purpose
    android.view.ViewGroup insertPoint = (android.view.ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.maincontainer);
    // New View that needs to be added
    android.view.LayoutInflater vi = (android.view.LayoutInflater)
            getApplicationContext().getSystemService(android.content.Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    android.view.View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.app_flow_error, insertPoint, false);

    android.widget.TextView textView = (android.widget.TextView) v.findViewById(cR.id.information_message);
    textView.setText("Showing error");

    //Defining the params value for new view that needs to be added

    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.addRule(android.widget.RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    insertPoint.addView(v,  layoutParams);

    v.setHovered(true);
```

P.S. please mark as answer after you checked it.

Comment: This solution is not working as v.getLayoutParams(); is returning "null". I tried different solution to check why v.getLayoutParams() is giving null , but i haven`t got any success.

Comment: did u use my complete code? I just checked it and it worked without any problem